# Phpmyadmin is not running on ubuntu

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have installed phpmyadmin, then I added this line to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` :

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

and save it.
After that, I ran this command :

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www
```

But it is still not working. Help me please :)

When I browse to `phpmyadmin` in my browser in get the source code, see the image below.

[image]

Comment: did you followed a particular tutorial? and how you're accessing phpmyadmin from browser?

Comment: I think that sum link should have been `/var/www/html`. Apache root should be `/var/www/html`

Comment: yes, i have linking to `/var/www/html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS you can follow these steps to install Apache2, MySQL, PHP7 and `phpmyadmin`, I tested this today and it shouln't give you any kind of problems, maybe you missed one of these steps, so please check them out:

1. Install Apache2:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install apache2
   ```
2. Edit the file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, add the following line at the end:

   ```
   ServerName <yourDomainOrIP>
   ```
3. Check if your config is OK:

   ```
   sudo apache2ctl configtest
   ```

The output should be like this: `Syntax OK`

4. Restart Apache to implement changes:

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart apache2
   ```
5. Verify if Apache is working, open you browser and go to: `http://your_ip_address`, you should see somehing like the following image:

[image: Apache Works]

6. Install MySQL:

   ```
   sudo apt install mysql-server
   ```

During this installation you will be asked to enter the MySQL password.

7. Secure your MySQL installation executing:

   ```
   sudo mysql_secure_installation
   ```

Choose the options that you prefer in this step.

8. Install PHP:

   ```
   sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt php-mysql
   ```
9. Edit the file `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf`, after editing it should look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml index.htm
</IfModule>
```

10. Restart Apache and check its status:

    ```
    sudo systemctl restart apache2
    sudo systemctl status apache2
    ```

After this step if you want to install PHP modules, you can search for them using:

```
apt-cache search php- | less
```

11. Test if PHP works, create an `info.php`:

    ```
    sudo nano /var/www/html/info.php
    ```

An put the following content inside:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Now go to `http://your_ip_address/info.php` and you should see something like the image below:

[image: PHP Info]

12. Install `phpmyadmin`:

    ```
    sudo apt install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext
    ```

During the installation you will be asked to choose your web server (apache2) and if you want to use `dbconfig-common` to configure the db, finally the password for `phpmyadmin` will be requested.

This process adds `phpmyadmin` to `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/`, you can verify it with: `ls /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/`

[image: ls /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/]

13. Enable PHP `mcrypt` and `mbstring`:

    ```
    sudo phpenmod mcrypt
    sudo phpenmod mbstring
    ```
14. Restart Apache again and test if everything works.

    ```
    sudo systemctl restart apache2
    ```

Go to `http://your_ip_address/phpmyadmin` and you will see the login page:

[image: phpmyadmin Login screen]

Enter your credentials and then you're done:

[image: phpmyadmin databases]

Hope it helps.

Comment: my ubuntu version is 17.04

Comment: Good to hear that it worked, If you find this answer useful you [may "accept" it](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) (by clicking on the tick mark (✓) next to it) so others may more easily find it in the future, also you can upvote the answer. =)

Comment: @galoget, I have tried but I am getting issues with  point 12 E: Unable to locate package php-gettext and point 13 WARNING: Module mcrypt ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/8.1/mods-available

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the somewhat same problem because I have created a symlink of a website in the following directory: `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` due to which it was blocking `phpmyadmin` from loading using `localhost/phpmyadmin` in the browser. I have removed the symlink from the directory using the following command: `rm somefilename.com.conf`. Use the name of your symlink instead of `somefilename` in the above command. Do not remove the default symlink from the folder.

You can see errors caused by apache2 using the following command: `sudo apache2ctl configtest`

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem is because of conflict between 2 modules: mpm_event and mpm_prefork. PhpMyAdmin prefers old versions of PHP.

1. You should disable module mpm_event by:

   sudo a2dismod mpm_event
2. Then enable mpm_prefork:

   sudo a2enmod mpm_prefork
3. After that you better to make sure does it work and what kind of conflicts it has:

   sudo a2enmod php[your_php_version]
4. Then restart Apache:

   sudo systemctl restart apache2

After that start your phpMyAdmin.